# What do most forum website build on? Dynamic or Static Websites?

Tags: javascript, vs-web-site-project

I'm planning to create a forum website from 0 for my portfolio and learning experience. What should I choose between static and dynamic? Since I just thought it might affect my website performance.

I know the basic difference between static and dynamic which is one is pre-built and the other is rendered from the server-side.

I have experience in react, express, axios, mongodb, and MySQL

Any suggestion?

Comment: The performance impact is neglible for all modern technologies, whether you render it in backend or in frontend (at least if you follow best practises). There is no sense why you should create a static forum website.

Comment: But don't get overwhelmed at the beginning. First start with a static page to get familiar with HTML/CSS. Afterwards you can try to make the site dynamic, for example with PHP or Angular + Backend of your choice.

Comment: @phip1611 So you're suggesting i should make a dynamic forum website? I have tried and made a few websites with react, express, axios, and MySQL. But I'm just not sure what most forum website use, static or dynamic

Comment: They are all dynamic. What big sites will do for better performance is caching of dynamically generated content. But you do not need this unless you have ~10 new visitors EVERY second ;)

Comment: Ahh, I see, thanks a lot. I'll try to learn dynamic website creation now.

Comment: "*I know the basic difference between static and dynamic*" - then certainly you also know which one to choose when it needs to be possible to add new posts or users to the forum.

Comment: I don't agree that it wouldn't matter. I want to see a static forum for smaller sites. As far as i know there are many static page generators but not a single static forum so far. And given the performance pigs most forums are it will make a huge difference. It could easily run of on a 512MB Website for $1 per month hosting cost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Big Forums are all dynamic websites.

> What big sites will do for better performance is caching of dynamically generated > content. But you do not need this unless you have ~10 new visitors EVERY second ;)

Quoted from @phip1611

Comment: Thats why i would love to see the alternative. It would also make a good use case for your portfolio. All forum scripts are extremely performance pigs for the little tasks they have to do.